# Cisco VPN client on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10-preview, cisco-vpn-client

I have been able to get the Cisco VPN client, the one which goes by  the name vpnclient-winx64-msi-5.0.07.0440-k9, on Windows 8.1 x64 machines.  Now I have a Windows 10 TP machine.

Has anyone gotten this client to install on 10?   I get the following:

*Error 27850. Unable to manage networking component.  Operating system corruption may be preventing installation.*

Ring any bells?  I also cannot get the Citrix DNE installed.  Very similar message.

[image]

Comment: I receive the same error on ***Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview, Build 10074***. All of the solutions I have found are for when the client is already installed and stops working after an updated build. 

If it helps, here is a screenshot of the Citrix DNE error (which was mentioned as a solution). http://i.stack.imgur.com/ytTWo.png

Comment: Did you install ftp://files.citrix.com/winfix.exe and reboot before trying to run the DNE update?  Check out my answer here: http://superuser.com/a/947894/138762

Comment: I'd like to point out though that the IPsec VPN Client's been EOL'd years ago, so a) compatibility will only get worse and worse and b) using it exposes serious security problems. AnyConnect OTOH installs and works flawlessly on Windows 10. Any reasons why you haven't migrated yet? It's quite cheap, really.

Answer (score 2):

I have a slightly different version: 5.0.07.0290 vs 5.0.07.0440. I got this client working with Windows 10 earlier this year and then just recently a Windows Update broke this again. Here's what I did to fix it:

I checked the registry for the key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\CVirtA`

The key didn't exist. I then went to: `Control Panel > Programs and Features > Cisco VPN Client` Then selected repair, and rebooted.

I checked the key again and it existed. I replaced the Display Name null string value (REG_SZ) that listed: `@oem8.inf,%CVirtA_Desc%;Cisco Systems VPN Adapter for 64-bit Windows` with the new value: `Cisco Systems VPN Adapter for 64-bit Windows`. I rebooted and it worked again.

To start from an uninstalled state, here's what I did in the past:

1. Uninstall any Cisco VPN client.
2. Install the Citrix DNE client: ftp://files.citrix.com/dneupdate64.msi
3. Reboot
4. Install the Cisco VPN client.
5. Reboot
6. Run Cisco VPN Client

If you don't see the client start, check services.msc or `Control Panel > Services` and ensure the service `Cisco Systems, Inc. VPN Service` is running.

As for your error, make sure you have a recent Windows 10 update and if it still isn't working possibly run the installer in compatibility mode for Windows 7. Another thing to try is a system file check. From an elevated command prompt, or powershell session, run the command: `sfc /scannow`.