# VPN client deleted during upgrade from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10

Tags: cisco-vpn-client

I had a Cisco VPN Client 5.0.7 installed in Windows 8.1, but when I upgraded to 10, my VPN client is gone from the system tray and gone from apps.  Why was this 'app' deleted during the upgrade?

Comment: What is the name of the VPN client app?

Comment: Cisco VPN Client 5.0.7

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/954102/alternative-to-cisco-vpn-client-on-windows-10

Comment: I suggest you just install the client again.  It likely was removed automatically because 5.0.7 does not support Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

It indicates during an upgrade in Windows 10 that it's incompatible with Windows 10 (I upgraded and saw this message briefly).  Use Shrewsoft VPN which will let you load in your PCF files from Cisco and it will cause you a lot less headaches.  It works really well under Windows 10 (including the 1607 version).